# Programmatically determining Controller of a particular drive on Linux

Tags: linux, device-driver, hard-drive, device

I have a VM configured with both a SATA and SCSI controller and one drive attached to each. I would like to determine which drive is attached to which controller in a Perl script. I am using the Debian squeeze kernel 2.6.32.

Comment: What does the drive *currently* look like to the script?

Comment: The script just sees it as /dev/sd?